# Creating a one-time password, and send the email

Tags: users

We need to create a system where the user enters only an email address. For a specific domain user receives an email with a generated password, and for all other domain receives a notification email to contact support. Password used to access a protected area of ​​the site that is not available to the public. Also, the password can be used only once, ie. each time a user enters an email address, get a new password.

Any ideas how to make this system to Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Login One Time](https://drupal.org/project/login_one_time) comes closest to your requirements. From its project page:

> Login one time provides the ability to email one-time login links to users.
>
> Features
>
> Rules:
>
> - [user:login-one-time] token on user events.
> - [comment:login-one-time] token for node author on comment event.
> - User profile - "Send login one time link" button.
> - VBO - Create a view and send login links to the view. Checkout View
>   Reference for ideas on how to embed views.
> - Block - Select a user and send the link. You can use this block in
>   nodes as a CCK field using Block Reference.
> - PHP - Print a button in a template or directly send the emails using
>   the functions described in the README.